# Error with stripe webhooks not incoming in correct order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I've been using the `stripe_event` gem for webhooks from stripe and today I found out that the webhooks seem to be not incoming in the right order. I'm storing a local copy of the charges made on stripe and I have the following setup

```rb
StripeEvent.configure do |events|
  events.subscribe 'payment_intent.created', CreateChargeRecord.new
  events.subscribe 'payment_intent.processing', UpdateChargeRecord.new
  events.subscribe 'payment_intent.succeeded', UpdateChargeRecord.new
end
```

Looking at the stripe dashboard the event `payment_intent.created` is always done before `payment_intent.processing`. Now I'm creating the charge record as follows

```rb
class CreateChargeRecord
  def call(event)
    charge_object = event.data.object
    Charge.create(
      user: User.find_by(stripe_id: charge_object.customer),
      receiver_id: User.find_by(merchant_id: charge_object.transfer_data.destination).id,
      amount: charge_object.amount / 100,
      currency: 'eur',
      application_fee_amount: charge_object.application_fee_amount / 100,
      status: charge_object.status,
      stripe_id: charge_object.id
    )
  end
end
```

and updating as follows

```rb
class UpdateChargeRecord
  def call(event)
    charge_object = event.data.object
    charge = Charge.find_by(stripe_id: charge_object.id)
    charge.update!(status: charge_object.status)
  end
end
```

the problem is that from the cli it seems that the webhook `payment_intent.processing` is being recieved before `payment_intent.created`

```
2021-10-10 22:08:50   --> payment_intent.processing 
2021-10-10 22:08:51   --> payment_intent.created 
2021-10-10 22:08:51  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:3000/webhooks/
2021-10-10 22:08:51  <--  [500] POST http://localhost:3000/webhooks/
```

which results in an error `NoMethodError (undefined method` update!' for nil:NilClass):` since I'm trying to update a record that doesn't exists yet.

Is there anything I can do here to prevent this since it seems that this is not a bug according to stripe?

Comment: The requests are asynchronous but you are trying to process them synchronously.  I would just store all the events keyed by their type and have some background job that matches run on an interval and updates any new payments with its status

Answer (score 1):

This is [expected and documented](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#event-ordering) -- events might be delivered out-of-order from the order in which they are generated.

To account for this, your application should be aware that this is possible and, for example, instead of using the payload you retrieve the latest object state directly from the API when the event is received.